# angular.js how do i set data what is response value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code.

```
$scope.data = {};
var s_data = {};

var no = $stateParams.no;
var data = {};
data.no = no;

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: settings.apiUrl+'/api/test,
  data:JSON.stringify(data)
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  s_data = data.results[0];
  $scope.data = data.results[0];
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  SweetAlert.swal("fail");
});
```

I need data what is first return value.
but if $scope.data is changed, s_data change with $scope.data.

How is it possible to set s_data in data.results[0]?

Comment: Some other minor problems... 1) You have an unclosed string literal at `'/api/test,`. 2) You are using the deprecated `success()` and `error()` callbacks. 3) You probably don't need to use `JSON.stringify` on the POST body

Answer (score 3):

In this case use copy

```
s_data = angular.copy(data.results[0]);
$scope.data = angular.copy(data.results[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.